# Why is ESP masked with 0xFFFFFFF0?

Tags: assembly, x86, elf

I have disassembled a program. I see at the beginning an `AND` instruction with `ESP` and `0xFFFFFFF0`.

What is the meaning of this mask? Is it an alignment problem?

It is an ELF executable for 32bit x86.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without context, but stack alignment is one reason you would do this.

Comment: It aligns the stack-pointer to 16 bytes (down in memory, so "up" in the stack)

Comment: What platform? What architecture? What compiler? What language? Your questions lacks critical information and cannot be answered as-is.

Comment: Okay thanks. I have read that data is stacked to the bottom from the top in memory. So if i want to see the stack in gdb, i should type x/16x $esp-15 ?

Comment: Yes, alignment, most any modern x86 or x64 compiler will use SSE2 instructions.  They require alignment to 16.

Comment: @HansPassant To be clear, there are SSE2+ instructions that require alignment, but there are also equivalent instructions that do not (ie : `movapd` vs `movupd`).  On earlier chips there was a significant penalty for the unaligned versions of the instructions but with newer chips (ie: Haswell+) there really isn't much difference anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant just out of curiosity, does that aligns 64 bit size integer as well? or you need a different mask?

Comment: You'd likely see 0xFFFFFF8 back.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Every multiple of 16 is also a multiple of 8.  Compilers do align 8-byte "objects" (like uint64_t) to their natural alignment.

Comment: @HansPassant: The 32bit SysV function-calling convention actually requires / guarantees 16-byte stack alignment these days.  It didn't used to, and aligning the stack was something gcc did as an unofficial ABI extension.

Answer (score 8):

gcc for i386 Linux defaults to [`-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4` (meaning 2<sup>4</sup> = 16 byte alignment)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mstackrealign-2877).  (Other non-Linux systems also use ELF executables, but they also have the same stack-alignment defaults and SysV ABI.)

Unlike clang, **gcc doesn't assume that the stack will be aligned on entry to `main`**, so it uses an `AND` instruction to mask off the low bits of the stack pointer.  This is the cheapest way to reserve enough padding on the stack to reach the next alignment boundary.

Stack alignment is the same reason you'll see a function that calls another function reserve some space on the stack that it doesn't use for anything:

```c
extern int bar(void);
int foo(int x) { return x+bar(); }

  gcc 5.3 -O3
    sub     esp, 12                   # align the stack for another call
    call    bar
    add     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+16]   # add our arg (from the stack) to bar()'s return value (in eax)
    add     esp, 12
    ret
```

[See this on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-fno-verbose-asm+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell+-m32',source:'extern+int+bar(void)%3B%0A%0Aint+foo(int+x)+%7B+return+x%2Bbar()%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0A%0A//+gcc+makes+some+pretty+weird+code%3B%0A//+it+could+just+make+a+stack+frame+with+ebp+before+aligning+the+stack%0A%0A//+clang+assumes+the+stack+is+aligned+on+entry%0Aint+main(void)+%7B+return+foo(10)%3B+%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), where you can try different compilers and options.

`-mincoming-stack-boundary=3` (or less) causes the stack-alignment boilerplate to be added to every function (not just main).  `-mstackrealign` and `-mno-stackrealign` has no effect on `foo()` or `main()`, with or without a small `-mincoming-stack-boundary`.  Based on [the documentation in the gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mstackrealign-2877), I thought it would enable or disable the alignment stuff for functions other than main, or for main.

---

The [32bit x86 SysV ABI](https://01.org/sites/default/files/file_attach/intel386-psabi-1.0.pdf) used to only guarantee 4-byte stack alignment, but the calling convention now guarantees 16-byte alignment of `%esp` before a `call` instruction.

> Section 2.2.2 The Stack Frame
>
> ... In other words, the value (`%esp + 4`) is always
>   a multiple of 16 when control is transferred to the function entry point.   (32 when a 32-byte ymm vector is passed by value)

So gcc's `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4` is not just a good idea, it's the law (on systems like Linux where the updated ABI version that includes this stronger guarantee is the official standard).  This makes it safe for functions other than `main` to omit that alignment step before using aligned SSE stores/loads to the stack.  Those instructions (like [`movaps`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVAPS.html)) will fault on unaligned addresses.  So alignment is required for correctness, not just performance.

---

#### The `AND` instruction isn't actually needed these days

The current version of the 32bit ABI *does* guarantee that a freshly-`execve`ed 32bit process will start with `%esp` 16-byte aligned.  (Section 2.3.1 Initial Stack and Register State, see the bullet point about the initial state of `%esp` itself, not the stack contents.)

This means that gcc's behaviour of aligning the stack at the start of main is now obsolete, assuming the CRT startup code that calls `main` doesn't misalign the stack.

clang does assume the stack is aligned at the start of main, like 64bit gcc does.

16B-alignment was part of the x86-64 SysV ABI from the start, not added later, so it was always a safe assumption and there are no old kernels that don't provide that at process startup.

The [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki has links to other ABIs, and much more.

Comment: Unfortunately that ABI change gratuitously broke ABI backwards compatibly.  It's also the "law" only so much as you consider the GNU version of the document officially superseding the actual System V ABI documentation.

Comment: @RossRidge: good catch, I missed that part of the answer when making it not purely Linux-specific, after realizing that the OP's statement of ELF 32bit x86 didn't narrow it down to only Linux.  I made an edit to point out that some systems might not use that version of the ABI document.  The x86 tag wiki does include a link to the old version [on SCO's site](http://sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf).  I'm not clear on who's  involved in updating the ABI for things like wider vectors, but it's not just the FSF / GNU.  IDK if any *BSD or Solaris people are involved...

Comment: Even on Linux it's not clear what makes it "official". The Linux kernel itself specifically doesn't use 16 byte stack alignment, and every Linux distribution is free make their own decisions on what they consider official. Most would have silently, and probably ignorantly, adopted the updated ABI with this change when they upgraded the compilers they used to build their user lands.

Comment: @RossRidge: The alignment at process-startup guarantee does require kernel support, but fair point that it's mostly a toolchain decision.

Comment: Hmm... interestingly while the Linux kernel ELF loader unconditionally uses 16-byte alignment regardless of architecture (or at least the current version does) both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of `crt1.o` on the Linux machine I use manually align the stack.

Comment: @RossRidge might it be for backwards compatibility with older kernels?

Comment: @Ruslan The would make sense for the 32-but `crt1,o` but like Peter Cordes said in his answer there shouldn't be any 64-bit kernels that don't provide 16-byte alignment at start.