# Why is the machine code generated for my C program different from what is given in the book?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I found this text in the book *Professional Assembly Language* by Richard Blum.

> The compiling step converts the text programming language statements
>   into the instruction codes required to carry out the application
>   function. Each of the HLL lines of code are matched up with one or
>   more instruction codes pertaining to the specific processor on which
>   the application will run. For example, the simple HLL code
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>     int i = 1;
>     exit(0);
> }
> ```
>
> is compiled into the following IA-32 instruction codes:
>
> ```
> 55
> 89 E5
> 83 EC 08
> C7 45 FC 01 00 00 00
> 83 EC 0C
> 6A 00
> E8 D1 FE FF FF
> ```

But when I try this program myself, I cannot reproduce these results.

First some details about my system and compiler.

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
8.3
$ uname -a
Linux debian1 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u2 (2016-01-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ dpkg -l gcc-multilib
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                      Version                   Architecture              Description
+++-=========================================-=========================-=========================-========================================================================================
ii  gcc-multilib                              4:4.9.2-2                 amd64                     GNU C compiler (multilib files)
```

Here is the program I wrote.

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    exit(0);
}
```

Here are the results I get after compiling only.

```
$ gcc -m32 -c foo.c
$ objdump -d foo.o 

foo.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   4:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   7:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   a:   55                      push   %ebp
   b:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   d:   51                      push   %ecx
   e:   83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp
  11:   c7 45 f4 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
  18:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
  1b:   6a 00                   push   $0x0
  1d:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1e <main+0x1e>
```

Here are the results I get after compiling and linking.

```
$ gcc -c foo.c
$ objdump -d a.out | grep -A15 "<main>"
080483fb <main>:
 80483fb:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 80483ff:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048402:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 8048405:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048406:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048408:   51                      push   %ecx
 8048409:   83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp
 804840c:   c7 45 f4 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048413:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 8048416:   6a 00                   push   $0x0
 8048418:   e8 c3 fe ff ff          call   80482e0 <exit@plt>
 804841d:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 804841f:   90                      nop

08048420 <__libc_csu_init>:
```

What can I do to reproduce the results provided by the author in the book?

Comment: Use the exact same compiler version with the exact same flags. Since there are many ways to generate asm code from C, you generally can't expect the same output from all compilers.

Comment: Does your book really not list the disassembly for that machine code?  That's kinda weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra instructions not in the book are:

```
80483fb:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
80483ff:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
8048402:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
8048408:   51                      push   %ecx
8048409:   83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp

...

804841d:   66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
804841f:   90                      nop
```

The first couple lines align the stack to a 16-byte boundary. This improves performance (arguments can't cross cache line boundary) and allow usage of SIMD instruction that only operate on 16-bit aligned addresses.

The `xchg %ax, %ax` at the end is a 2-byte NOP. The 3 bytes of nop don't matter because they are unreachable anyway. They are there to pad the `__libc_csu_init` function to a suitable alignment.

As for why the assembly differs, assembly is a programming language and there's usually more than one way to do things. You can't expect a C program to give the same output across compilers, versions of the same compiler or configurations of the same version.

In your specific case, the 16-bit stack alignment is due to [`-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) and the 3 byte `nop` due to [`-falign-functions`](http://falign%20functions%2016).

These are configured as default arguments when you call `gcc`. Either directly or by being required by `-O2` or similar.

Comment: Note that `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4` (or higher) is now [required by the current version of the ABI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967710/why-is-esp-masked-with-0xfffffff0/37972101#37972101).  Also that gcc could (and clang does) omit that stuff from `main`, because CRT startup code keeps the stack aligned after Linux starts the process with the stack 16B-aligned.  But yes, the 3 bytes of NOP are just padding before the NEXT function, not part of the current function.  It ended at the `call` to a noreturn function (`exit`).

Comment: I wonder why it bothers to `call` a noreturn function, instead of simply unconditionally jumping to it. Is there something obvious I'm missing, @peter?

Comment: @CodyGray: IDK why tail-call optimization didn't happen.  I wondered the same thing.  I don't *think* we're both missing something obvious.  I mean, it will just crash if the function does return, and `exit(3)` guarantees that the function can't fail.  I'd guess that gcc just doesn't have that peephole optimization of using `jmp` for noreturn functions when it would mean an abnormal stack-frame.  Oh right, `call` pushes a return address, so `exit` looks for its arg above that.  gcc could have emitted `mov $0, 4(%esp)` / `jmp exit@plt`, but that's a weirder peephole (and worse code-size)