# Assembly and callstack

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to get an understanding of assembly but unfortunately I have problems to understand the following C code in assembly:

```
void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

    int flag;
    char buffer[10]

    flag = 31337;
    buffer[0] = 'A';

}

int main() {

    test_fuction(1,2,3,4);

}
```

The assembly of `main()` looks like this:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp,0x18
and esp,0xffffffff0
mov eax,0x0
sub esp,eax
mov DWORD PTR [esp+12], 0x4
mov DWORD PTR [esp+12], 0x3
mov DWORD PTR [esp+12], 0x2
mov DWORD PTR [esp+12], 0x1
call <test_function>
```

The assembly for `test_function(...)` looks like this:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp,0x28
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 0x7a69 ;this is 31337 in hexadecimal
mov BYTE PTR [ebp-40], 0x41    ;this is the 'A' in ASCII
leave
ret
```

What is hard for me to understand is:

```
and esp,0xffffffff0
mov eax,0x0
sub esp,eax
```

Why are we operating an `and` with `0xffffffff0` on `esp`?
And why do we move a `0` to `eax` and `sub` the content of `eax` from `esp`?

Second:
Through `sub esp,0x28` we are allocating 40 bytes of RAM. Why 40? The integer and the 10 `char`s of the array are altogether only 14 bytes, aren't they?
And why are we moving `0x7a69` to the position `[ebp-12]` and not to `[ebp]`? By operating `mov ebp, esp` I set `ebp` to the current `ESP`. Now `ESP` is pointing to the end of the stack. The last value I pushed on the stack was the `ebp` by operating `push ebp`. So `EBP` (= `esp`) points behind the saved `ebp`. So why couldn't I move `0x7a69` to `[ebp]` just directly behind the saved `EBP`?
And why is the 'A' moved to [ebp-40]?

Comment: what compiler/version, are you optimizing?

Comment: I assume this isnt the exact code as it has a bug in the test function.

Comment: I'm using ggc under Linux, but this is a copy from a book: https://www.amazon.com/Hacking-Art-Exploitation-Jon-Erickson/dp/1593271441/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1515250375&sr=8-1&keywords=hacking+the+art+of+exploitation%2C+2nd+edition

Comment: LOL, mine is even worse, optimized it is dead code of course so the function simply returns.  unoptimized I get an rsp adjustment of 0x40 bytes.  Along with using test function names not main you should construct your test functions such that they are not dead code that optimizes away (perform operations on the operands and return something based on that), and then use the optimizer to remove the more confusing code, until later when you have a better grasp on what is going on

Comment: There are two questions here (... three? four?). If it was only one, this would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37967710/2564301.

Comment: ahh, well no reason to expect any two or any two versions of a compiler to produce the same code so you just have to go with whatever the book's authors compiler that day produced.

Comment: Did you type in the code and/or asm manually?  There's a missing semicolon after `char buffer[10]`, and your asm for `main` rewrites the same arg 4 times instead of storing for different args.  No version of gcc would have produced that as part of calling a function, even at `-O0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be some standard compiler-generated assembler.

```
and esp,0xffffffff0
mov eax,0x0
sub esp,eax
```

The `and` will make `esp` a multiple of 16, i.e. alligns it on 16 bytes. Because the stack grows *downward* it is essentially a substraction, not an addition.

The next `mov` and `add` reserve space for the local variables. in `main` there are no local variables, so their total is `0x0`. Because `test_function` has local variables, `0x28` is moved to `eax` and added to `esp`. Probably the compiler has also alligned this on some multiple. Lastly, `[ebp-40]` is the location on the reserved stack space the compiler has assigned to `buffer`.

Comment: The OP's `test_function` doesn't touch `eax`.  I don't understand why `main` is using mov / sub there instead of an immediate `sub`, or in fact why it's doing a `sub` at all after already allocating enough space to store the stack args.  But clearly that's not the correct code because it stores all 4 function args to `[esp+12]` without modifying `esp` in between.

Comment: Thank you very much so far. =) I think i should at first learn some assembly basics for better understanding. This book explained it a bit but the focus is on C. The book only wants to teach you how to read some assembly but i'd like to code it as well so i think i should at first learn how to code assembly. :)